# Spark-submit on kubernetes, executor pods are still running even after spark job is finished. Due to which the resources are not free for new jobs

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, spark-submit

We are submitting spark job into kubernetes cluster using cluster mode and with some more memory configurations. My job is finishing in about 5 mins but my executor pods are still running after 30 - 40 mins. Due to this the new jobs are pending as the resources are still bound to running pods.

Below is spark submit command :

`/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class com.Spark.MyMainClass --driver-memory 3g --driver-cores 1 --executor-memory 12g --executor-cores 3 --master k8s://https://masterhost:6443 --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=default --conf spark.app.name=myapp1 --conf spark.executor.instances=3 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=myappdriver1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=imagePath --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image=imagePath --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image=imagePath local:///opt/spark/jars/MyApp.jar`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

```
sparkSession.stop()
```

at the end of your code

Comment: And what about the driver? If it still running?

Comment: Wasn't enough for me, had to include `System.exit(0)` after the `sparkSession.stop()`